# monitoring CPU/mem usage on gke

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I recently launched with gke and kubernetes in production.
I have regular outages with no obvious reasons.
No event shows anything, pods are not restarting and seems stable.
I have a similar qa env that has no issue at all whereas it's way smaller.

Where can I find potential infos on the outage reason?

Answer (score 7):

Stack driver makes you pay and configure it... kubernetes comes with a tool for it... just use this:

`kubectl top nodes`

```
al@host:~/$ kubectl top nodes
NAME                             CPU(cores)   CPU%      MEMORY(bytes)   MEMORY%
gke-learn-pool-1-10f60e0a-s44c   104m         11%       1008Mi          86%
```

You can also go under clusters -> Cluster -> nodes -> Node

[image]

Update: Stack Driver deprecated all load monitoring plugins. It's K8s or the highway now.

Answer (score 4):

You can see monitoring data for your cluster using [Stackdriver](http://app.google.stackdriver.com/). There's a brief walkthrough of how to use it for GKE in [this blog post](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2015/12/monitoring-Container-Engine-with-Google-Cloud-Monitoring.html). You may also want to check out the general [Kubernetes application troubleshooting guide](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/application-troubleshooting/).

What are the symptoms of the outage?

Comment: I have already looked at stackdriver as well as the kubernetes /ui. I can see the men usage graph on the /ui (very limited and small) but I can't see any CPU/mem info at the container level on stackdriver. The outage is quite simple, the request on port 443 timeout. That said, I don't know yet at which level it times out, it seems to be at the first layer, my own nginx but I can't see any CPU stress on the nodes, no errors in the logs and no CPU usage detail at the container level on the stackdriver interface.

Comment: Stackdriver does indeed have per-container CPU and memory metrics. In the view of your cluster, if you click on a pod, the pod details page will have a list of containers. If you click on the container, it'll show you metrics and events for just that container. See the list of pods on this screenshot from the blog post? https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-RVrPCkoQvGY/VnH2tA8mbJI/AAAAAAAACLQ/KP5JthWTFbw/s1600/cloud%2Bmonitoring%2B2.png

Comment: I see the instances cpu and mem. I can't see it on the container level (pod level), it says "no graph data found" for all my pods.

Comment: Do you see anything at https://app.google.stackdriver.com/gke ? If you run `gcloud container clusters describe $CLUSTERNAME` what's the value of the `monitoringService` field?

Comment: Yes, all the comments I made before were coming from app.google.stackdriver.com/gke: I can see instances monitoring but when I click on pods, it says "no graph data".

monitoringService: monitoring.googleapis.com

Comment: Should I be able to see the graph at the container level?

Comment: Yes, you should have been. There was an issue with the graphs for clusters at version 1.2 that's now been fixed, so if you still can't see anything, please let me know. Thanks for bringing this up!

Comment: I've been looking around the graphs, I see crazy numbers, like 2500% for the cpu, what is this supposed to mean?

Comment: Utilization for each container is usage divided by the limit specified in the pod manifest. It's not impossible to hit 2500% utilization if your pod's CPU limit is really small, like 0.1 CPUs, then if it's using 2.5 CPUs you'd see a utilization of 2500%. This would be possible because the limit isn't currently enforced except when there's contention for the CPUs.

Comment: ok, perfect! thanks for the info, it's clearer now, maybe it should be written somewhere (% of the limit or % of the request). I also see that the graph have changed this morning! Great!

Comment: @AlexRobinson I still see "No graph data found" in recent pods. Will this work for short-lived containers, e.g. running less than 1 min?